# how to plot a stationary series without using o marker

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization

I have a series where values are not changing, ie all the values are centered at one point. I am trying to plot it using Matplotlib, but I can't see it on the plot. What I am doing wrong? id there any way around it?

```
x_values1 = [2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5]
y_values1 = [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]

# Create a new figure and plot the XY coordinates
plt.figure(figsize=(1, 3))  # Adjust the figure size as needed
plt.plot(x_values1, y_values1, label='Series 1')
plt.show()
```

The same code is working for any other series that has varying data.

I was expecting to see something on the plot, most probably a tiny dot. I changed the scale hoping that on a smaller scale, it might become visible.
I have multiple series some are stationary and some not. and I have to make then appear as a path hence using marker - or default. Using o makes stationary series fine but destroys the other series.[The plot of series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZXOU.png)  Instead of looking like sample b it series has to look like sample a where as using o/. as marker make it look like sample b. which is ok for stationary series but not others.

Comment: `plt.plot(x_values1, y_values1, 'o', label='Series 1')`